# rowsGroup datatables

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc

Я совсем новичок в программировании. Не получается добиться rowsGroup.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private SContext db = new SContext();

    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public string Lowx()
    {
        var query = (from Cars in db.Cars
                     select new
                     {
                         FirstName = Cars.FirstName,
                         LastName = Cars.LastName,
                         MiddleName = Cars.MiddleName,
                         BirthDate = Cars.BirthDate,
                         CarName = Cars.CarName,
                         CarNumber = Cars.CarNumber
                     }).ToList()
        .Select(x => new Car()
        {
            FirstName = x.FirstName,
            LastName = x.LastName,
            MiddleName = x.MiddleName,
            BirthDate = x.BirthDate,
            CarName = x.CarName,
            CarNumber = x.CarNumber
        });

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.ToList());
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Service</title>
</head>

    <p>
        <h1 align="center"> Сервис по обслуживанию автомобилей</h1>
        @*@Html.ActionLink("Добавить запись", "Create")*@
        <ul id="nav">
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Обновить", "Index")*@
            <li><a href="index.html">Обновить</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href='@Url.Action("Create")'><img src='/Content/addlow.png' width="40" 
          height="40" /></a>
    </p>
    <table class="table" id="cars">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Имя</th>
                <th>Фамилия</th>
                <th>Отчество</th>
                <th>Дата рождения</th>
                <th>Марка машины</th>
                <th>Гос.номер</th>    
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive- 
     ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function (data) {
          $('#cars').DataTable({
              ajax: {
                  url: '@Url.Action("lowx")',
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  dataSrc: ""    
              },
              columns: [
                  { data: "FirstName", name: "FirstName" },
                  { data: "LastName", name: "LastName" },
                  { data: "MiddleName", name: "MiddleName" },
                  { data: "BirthDate", name: "BirthDate" },
                  { data: "CarName", name: "CarName" },
                  { data: "CarNumber", name: "CarNumber" },    
              ],
```

Проблема где-то здесь

```
              data:data,
              rowsGroup: [
                  'MiddleName:name',
                 ],
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Указывайте только участки кода, в которых, как вы думаете, есть проблема и описывайте ее подробно, а не вываливайте полностью контроллер с представлением. Так отвечающим будет проще разобраться и вы быстрее получите ответ.

Comment: Указал, проблема в конце кода